# Flutter: Bottom sheet animation behind a button

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, bottom-sheet

At the bottom of the screen is a button. When the button is pressed, a bottom sheet should slide up behind the button.

I'm failing to get the animation right. I tried using a stack.

In the following flutter code, the bottom sheet doesn't slide up from the bottom of the screen but from the upper side of the button. How can I fix it?

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BottomSheetExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const BottomSheetExample({super.key});

  @override
  State<BottomSheetExample> createState() => _BottomSheetExampleState();
}

class _BottomSheetExampleState extends State<BottomSheetExample> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      bottomSheet: MyBottomSheet(),
      body: Center(child: Text('Body')),
    );
  }
}

class MyBottomSheet extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyBottomSheet({super.key});

  @override
  MyBottomSheetState createState() => MyBottomSheetState();
}

class MyBottomSheetState extends State<MyBottomSheet> {
  double _size = 100;
  bool _large = false;

  void _updateSize() {
    setState(() {
      _large = !_large;
      _size = _large ? 200 : 100;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomSheet(
      onClosing: () {},
      builder: (BuildContext context) => Stack(
        children: [
          AnimatedSize(
            curve: Curves.elasticOut,
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.amber,
              height: _size,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: const Center(child: Text('Bottom Sheet')),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            bottom: 10,
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => _updateSize(),
              child: const Text("Toggle"),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this one. Its easy to mess up with stack. I used here `AnimatedContainer` for the sake of simplicity, but normally you can use also `AnimatedSize` with no problem. If you have any questions, feel free to ask!

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  var _isExpanded;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _isExpanded = false;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomStart,
      children: [
        Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.amber,
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.purple,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Stack(
          alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomCenter,
          children: [
            AnimatedContainer(
              height: _isExpanded ? 100 : 0,
              color: Colors.blue,
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
            ),
            TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _isExpanded = !_isExpanded;
                  });
                },
                style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
                ),
                child: const Text('Press me!')),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But the animated box shows up above the button and not behind.

Comment: So I played around with your code. When I replace your last Column with a Stack it's pretty much what I needed.

Comment: I was about to comment this. I will edit my code above. please mark it as a solution. thanks